# Jquery, change border if div is present but only from that item in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items like this:

```
<div class="wine"> <H1>Title</H1> <div class="promotion"></div></div>
<div class="wine"> <H1>Title</H1> </div></div>
<div class="wine"> <H1>Title</H1> </div></div>
<div class="wine"> <H1>Title</H1> <div class="promotion"></div></div>
```

When the div .promotion exists in the wine dive i want to give the wine class a red border. But only for that element of course not for all the wine classes..

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` in your middle two divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method on `.wine` to check if it has `.promotion`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e58QY/)**

```
$('.wine').has('.promotion').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.parent()` selector to do this like so:

```
$('.promotion').parent('.wine').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
```

Here is a fiddle showing it off: http://jsfiddle.net/33Ugf/

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you need to remove redundant closing `</div>` tag after second and third `<div class="wine">` to make your HTML markup correct.

After that, you can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**:

```
$('.promotion').closest('.wine').css('border','1px solid red');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wKLqw/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wine:has(div.promotion)').css('border','1px solid red')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YCR6W/)**